# How to load localhost javascript page from Microsoft IE WebBrowser control without warning?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser

When I load a page from localhost, the IE warn that "To protect your security, your browser has restricted this file from showing active content that could access your computer". How can I avoid this warning? I'm loading it from my WebBrowser Control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably my favorite question on the whole Internets.  Allows me to say WTF MS? every time I answer it.

Mark Of The Web is the answer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx

WTF, Microsoft?